# In AS3, how can you store, retrieve and reuse arguments provided by an ellipsis (...) parameter?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, syntax, flash

I have a class that inherits from NetConnection, with the following function:

```
override public function connect(command:String, ... arguments):void
{
    addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
    super.connect(command, arguments);
}
```

What I want to do is effectively this:

```
override public function connect(command:String, ... arguments):void
{
    m_iTries = 0;
    m_strCommand = command;
    m_arguments = arguments;
    addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
    super.connect(command, arguments);
}

private function onNetStatus(pEvent:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    if (/* some logic involving the code and the value of m_iTries */)
    {
        super.connect(m_strCommand, m_arguments);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

Is this possible in AS3?  If so, how?  How would I declare the variable, set it, pass it into the function, etc.?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying your code above doesn't work? I've never tried it, but your code above is how I expect it would work. The `arguments` parameter is an `Array` so you just declare a member variable (private var m_argument:Array), and assign it as you have done. Alas, what seems simple may not actually work :)

Comment: It doesn't look that would be able to work.  Thanks though!

"If you pass an instance of the Array class, the entire array is placed into a single element of the ... (rest) parameter array."

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#..._%28rest%29_parameter

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks for explaining... going to think about this, now that I understand :)

Comment: You'd need to use Function.apply() to make it work as written, e.g. `super.connect.apply(super, m_arguments);` - that allows you to pass an array as if it were a list of arguments. Note, though, that you'd have to add "command" to the array before passing it to super.connect.apply.

Comment: @TheKaneda good call, you should post that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in `connect`:

```
 ...
 // Add m_strCommand to the start of the arguments array:
 m_arguments.unshift(m_strCommand); 
 ...
```

And in `onNetStatus`:

```
if (/* some logic... */)
{
    // .apply calls the function with first parameter as the value of "this". 
    // The second parameter is an array that will be "expanded" to be passed as 
    // if it were a normal argument list:
    super.connect.apply(this, m_arguments);
}
```

This means that calling e.g. (bogus arguments):

```
myNetConnection.connect("mycommand", 1, true, "hello");
```

will result in what amounts to this call from `onNetStatus`:

```
super.connect("mycommand", 1, true, "hello");
```

More about `.apply()`: http://adobe.ly/URss7b